# Laravel Undefined variable: intent Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I tried looking for all the possible solutions none of it worked and this is very basic trying to send data from a controller to view in Laravel.

Paymentcontroller

```
public function payment() {
        $plans =[
          'Basic' => "Monthly"
       ];

       $intent = $user->createSetupIntent();

        return view('pages.subscription', compact('intent', 'plans'));
    }
```

PageController

```
    public function index(string $page)
    {
        if (view()->exists("pages.{$page}")) {
            return view("pages.{$page}");
        }

        return abort(404);
    }
```

View pages.subscription

```
<div>
    {{ $intent }}
</div>
```

route

```
Route::get('{page}', ['as' => 'page.index', 'uses' => 'PageController@index']);

Route::get('/subscription', 'PaymentController@payment');
```

This makes the page work but doesn't display the data[image]

Comment: in your controller before `return`, set this code `dd($intent, $plans);` and see what are you sending to view.

Comment: Hi I did try dd($intent, $plans). It didn't display anything. I changed the route and it did I think so it because of
`Route::get('{page}', ['as' => 'page.index', 'uses' => 'PageController@index']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `Route::get('/subscription', 'PaymentController@payment');` before `Route::get('{page}',....` (it should be your last route in the list).

Currently when you call /subscription endpoint you are calling `PageController@index`, but it doesn't contain logic of your `PaymentController@payment` and doesn't pass any data to view.